# Is there a fix for an NXT reporting "File error!" when running an EV3 program?

Tags: mindstorms, nxt, ev3

I downloaded the new EV3 software from Lego and installed it on Windows 7.  The EV3 software runs.  I plugged in an NXT using a USB cable.  EV3 can edit the memory on the NXT and remove programs/sounds/text files.

I created a program that uses the large motor to spin the B motor 1 rotation at 75% power.  The end program block finishes the very small program.

It downloads without complaint.  Run it and the NXT complains with "File error!".

Is this a known problem?
Is there a fix?

The NXT has firmware 1.05 loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I needed to update the firmware. 1.05 was too old. 1.31 works.

Download from:
http://mindstorms.lego.com/en-us/support/files/default.aspx#Firmware

I did need to run the old NXT-G software to download the newer firmware.  I did not try to download the firmware using EV3.

Answer (score 1):

First off Ev3 and Nxt are different machines. However, it's most likely the firmware. I've just downloaded my firmware for Ev3 and I also tried out a program I made. It downloaded perfectly but when I tried to start it, it said "FILE NAME ERROR", which I believe is similar to your problem. I either recommend re-downloading the firmware or turning the Ev3 or Nxt off then trying it again.

Comment: I only have an NXT brick.  The question concerned using EV3 software to create a program and download the program to an NXT brick.  The NXT needed newer firmware.

Comment: The NXT won't take programs from the EV3 programming environment!

Comment: Actually, the NXT does accept programs written in EV3-G. It did require a firmware upgrade.